# Apache CXF Request/Response

Tags: web-services, http, servlets, soap, cxf

I am working on an application that I want to use to catch a SOAP request when it goes into the CXFServlet. There is some processing I need to do to the SOAP envelope on the server side, before the CXFServlet processes it.

I have been presuming that the SOAP envelope, once it reaches the server side, is one of the parameters in the HTTPServletRequest object. But looking at what comes in (using a debugger, of course), I cannot find it.

Can someone tell me where the SOAP request goes when a client sends it to the server? I know that the client is sending the request using an HTTP POST, and I know that the server is using information in the request in order to access the appropriate web service method, then placing any return values from the method into a SOAP response and returning it to the client. What I need to know is where where does the CXFServlet (or one of its filters) look in order to get the SOAP information? Is it somewhere in the parameters? In the servlet context? Does a filter process the SOAP information before it gets to the CXFServlet? How can I get that envelope and do things to it before the web service method is called?

Someone please advise...

Comment: Do you want to access the original request ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to access the original request ? If yes the actual request or response object itself can be accessed using the WebServiceContext object.

First, declare a private field for the WebServiceContext in your service implementation, and annotate it as a resource

@Resource
private WebServiceContext context;

Then, within your implementing methods, you can access the MessageContext, HttpServletRequest, and HttpServletResponse as follows:

MessageContext ctx = context.getMessageContext();

HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)ctx.get(AbstractHTTPDestination.HTTP_REQUEST);

For more info about WebServiceContext  see the following url :
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/WebServiceContext.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need to intercept the request before it is ever processed by the CXFServlet, you should look at developing a Servlet [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html).

If you just want to process the SOAP message before CXF does, you can likely use a [CXF Interceptor](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html).  The phases noted in the documentation indicate the points you can intercept the message.  Depending on what you want to do/change, you may need to play around with the phases.

The source for CXF's [SoapHeaderInterceptor](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/binding/soap/interceptor/SoapHeaderInterceptor.html) or [SoapActionInInterceptor](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/binding/soap/interceptor/SoapActionInInterceptor.html) would be  good places to start looking at how to work with the SOAP message.

Comment: Patrick: You are close to what I am looking for, but I should be more precise: Wht I want to do is send a request to a servlet, which does some processing and "injects" a SOAP envelope into the CXFServlet. The idea is that CXF should process the SOAP envelope as it normally does, but I am generating that envelope from another servlet. Is this possible with CXF?

Comment: Is there any reason the Servlet receiving the request cannot simply act as a jaxws client to the CXF web service?  That seems a simpler approach.  You could also try to use a CXF Interceptor to modify the input stream of the message before CXF starts to process it.  I am not sure what it would mean to "inject" a SOAP envelope into CXFServlet.  Perhaps you could describe the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Actually, yes. I need to directly manipulate the SOAP envelope, and in some cases, create custom SOAP requests. The idea is that a non- SOAP request goes to Servlet A, Servlet A generates the request, then forwards it to the CXFServlet. Or a client sends a SOAP request to Servlet B, Servlet B makes some alterations and additions, then forwards the altered request to CXFServlet. The important thing is the direct manipulation of the SOAP envelope, independently of CXFServlet -- something I can't do with a servlet client or intercepters...

Comment: Using ActionIntercepters or even HeaderIntercepters to do what I need will only work for already properly formed SOAP envelopes. In many cases, I will not be using a SOAP client to talk to the service. I need an intermediary that can either generate or make alterations to the SOAP information *before* the CXFServlet even sees it. It is the required manipulation of the SOAP envelope that also makes it unfeasible to use the servlet as a client to the CXFServlet. A SOAP client can only call the service. Also: both CXFServlet and my intermediary must run on the same machine.

Comment: Check out this article on [CXF Raw SOAP Envelope via Interceptor](http://bytearray.brixtonjunkies.com/2009/11/03/cxf-raw-soap-envelope-via-interceptor/).  Interceptors can modify the raw data before it is processed as a SOAP message.  This data could start as something other than a SOAP message, as you are catching it early, and using the interceptor to turn it into a SOAP message.  Actually creating the SOAP message by hand is another question.